# Rename columns with whitespaces using an alias in a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias, whitespace, dbt

I need to rename a column with a select statement, but I can't since there are whitespaces in the column header.

I am using dbt which means I cannot rename column headers normally using an alter statement. I'm trying to select the column that has whitespaces and rename it using an alias, and while the column is successfully renamed the entire column becomes null. None of the original values are kept. Here is the query:

```
select "column A" as A from my_table
```

How do I fix the query so that I can rename this column?

Comment: The query looks correct, it selects the column named `"column A"` with the alias `a`. But that doesn't "rename" the column in the table, only for the query. https://dbfiddle.uk/vn9l3Kks

Comment: "while the column is successfully renamed the entire column becomes null" This is quite difficult to believe. Do you see the same thing in psql, or is it just dbt?

Comment: Actually that's ok! I only need to rename for the select, as dbt works off of select statements. So why doesn't the query produce anything in the columns? All my contents disappear with this query.

Comment: Then there are no contents in that column...

Answer (score 0):

since it's a schema change, you need to redo the schema on the target using:

```bash
dbt run --full-refresh
```

if these columns come with space from the source, you can create a model just to rename these columns as a first step, and reference this model in the next models with the renamed columns, best practice.